# npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

So this error randomly popped up while I was working on my project:

[image]

I've searched online and most of the answers ask to run `npm cache clean --force`.
**This did not work for me :(**

I've also tried to reinstall npm but still get the same error.

Here is the error-log:

[image: Error-verbose]

I've been stuck on this for a while hoping someone can help me out :/

Comment: Looks like the package-lock.json file has been corrupted. Fix it to be _valid_ JSON.

Comment: @user2864740 brother you are a life saver. This worked for me, very weird tho, do you have any idea how this might have happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to reinstall entirely nodejs from your computer. This could solve the problem.

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try "yarn" instead of npm.

Installation (If you are using Mac):

`brew install yarn`

Or check here
https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/

Then just run (Works like "npm install")

```
yarn
```

Answer (score 1):

try `npm cache clean --force`, fixed the issue for me.

ref: [npm-err-unexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-743](https://dev.to/rishiabee/npm-err-unexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-743)

Answer (score 0):

For my Vue.js project this problem was solved by first deleting the package-lock.json file and then running `npm install`

Comment from [@user2864740](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2864740/user2864740) helped point me in this direction, thank you!